# MySQL Workbench Connection to Raspbian Stretch mariadb not working

Tags: mysql, raspberry-pi, mariadb, mysql-workbench, raspbian

I just setup a Raspberry Pi with the latest Raspbian Stretch distribution and have been trying to connect to it remotely using a TCP/SSH connection in MySQL Workbench. I keep getting the following error:

[image: MySQL Workbench error]

I have been researching solutions and I haven't been able to resolve the issue. Here are some of the things I've tried:

**Make Sure MySQL is running and root user has permission**

[image]

**Change bind-address in mysql config file**

Because Raspbian Stretch uses mariadb, I found this option in a different file than most solutions showed. I found it in /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf

[image]

**Grant privileges to root user**

I tried to run this query, but I kept getting syntax errors:

[image]

But I did check in the users table of phpmyadmin and found this:

[image]

So it seems that the user is set up correctly

**Make sure the service is listening on the right port**

[image]

**Allow tcp forwarding**

I also set AllowTcpForwarding to 'yes' in my /etc/ssh/sshd_config

[image]

As far as I can tell, everything looks correct. But I still get an error.

I even tried uninstalling and reinstalling mariadb and mysql, but I get the same thing.

I had no problems doing this before when I was on the wheezy version of Raspbian. Is it just a mariadb incompatibility issue?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you specifying the database host in your connection?  The error message is looking at the localhost (127.0.0.1) for the database.